# Flight Time encroaching any portion of a period python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, overlap

I need to determine if a flight is a night flight or not. A flight has a departure time and an arrival time.
A nightflight is defined as a flight which encroaches any portion between 00:00 and 02:59.
I have 3 flights with their respective departure and arrival times:

- 16/01/2018 18:30 → 16/01/2018 20:25 which is **not** a night flight
- 16/01/2018 21:35 → 17/01/2018 01:15, which is a night flight
- 17/01/2018 23:30 → 18/01/2018 03:25, which is a night flight

There is the problem with following code:

```
def is_night_duty(self):
    start_night = time(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
    end_night = time(hour=2, minute=59, second=59)
    for flight in self.get_flights():
        if start_night <= flight.departure().time.time() <= end_night or start_night<= flight.arrival().time.time() <= end_night:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Without more context, I would suggest testing that you have inequality working. Adding some print statements (e.g. `print(start_night)` and `print(flight.departure().time.time())`) can also help you do a sanity check.

Comment: The inequalities are working, it is when the departure time of a flight is earlier than 00:00 and the arrival time of that flight is later than 02:59 that gives the problem.

Comment: Add the following checks to your if statement: flighttime is greater than or equal to 24 hours OR (the start time is before the start of night AND the end time is after the end of night AND the start time is after the end time)